# How to find the critical gain K from the root locus

Tags: control, control-system

I am going through Ogata's Discrete-Time Control Systems and working out the following problem found on Page 262.

The problem states:

> Draw root locus diagrams in the \$z\$ plane for the system shown in Figure 4-45 for the
>   following three sampling periods: \$T = 2\$ sec

[image: digital control system block diagram]

I first obtain the Z-transform of G(s):

[image]

and I worked all the way till the very end and calculated break-away and break-in points to arrive at:

[image]

and root locus:

[image: Derivation of G(z) from G(s) with a ZOH]

However I am unable to calculate the critical value \$K\$ for stability (Answer is 1.4557).

I know I need to use the magnitude condition but I am not sure which value of \$z\$ I should substitute in the formula to obtain the critical value of \$K\$.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root locus, and the locus of \$\small \mid z\mid=1\$ are both unit circles. The centre of the \$\small \mid z\mid=1\$ circle is at the origin, and the centre of the root locus circle is at \$\small x=-0.5232\$. We need to find either one of the two complex conjugate points where these circles intersect, and we can then determine the value of \$\small K_{cr}\$.

Thus we have the two loci:

\$\small x^2 +y^2=1\$

\$\small (x+a)^2+y^2=1\$

Solving these simultaneously gives:

\$x=-\frac{a}{2}\$

Hence, the circles intersect at:

\$x=\frac{-0.5232}{2}=\small-0.2616\$

and the corresponding \$y\$ values are \$y=\small \pm 0.9652\$

Expressing this in complex form:

\$z=\small-0.2616\pm j0.9652 \$

Now substitute one of these values in the characteristic equation, and \$\small K_{cr}\$ is determined.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions would be appreciated.

You get the poles, for the closed-loop system \$ L(z) = \frac{G(z)}{1+G(z)}\$, moving on those root locus trajectories by changing the gain \$K\$. And you want to find the critical gain \$K\$ such that the poles are on the unit circle. Summing up the mathematics:

- \$ G(z) = \frac{1.1353K(z+0.5232)}{(z-1)(z-0.1353)} \$,
- \$ L(z) = \frac{\frac{1.1353K(z+0.5232)}{(z-1)(z-0.1353)}}{1+\frac{1.1353K(z+0.5232)}{(z-1)(z-0.1353)}} = \frac{1.1353K(z+0.5232)}{(z-1)(z-0.1353)+1.1353K(z+0.5232)}\$,
- \$|z_0| = 1\$.

Now, to solve this, expand the denominator of \$L(z)\$ (since its roots are the poles of the transfer function), then find the roots of the denominator, which is a second-degree polynomial, you will get some

$$z_0 = \frac{-b ~\pm ~\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},$$

Now, from the breakpoints and a sketch of the root locus you know that \$ z_0 \$ has a real part and an imaginary one, \$b\$ is the real part and the square root will be the imaginary one. You also know that \$|z_0| = 1\$, so combine that to have

$$ |z_0|^2 = 1 = \left(\frac{b}{2a}  \right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}{2a} \right)^2,$$

Which will only have \$ K\$ as an unknown.

obs: really long maths, if anyone ever do the numeric calculation feel free to update this.